# Ocultar elementos en PDF incrustado

Tags: php, pdf

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda con lo siguiente.

Tengo un PDF creado dinámicamente con PHP e incrustado de la siguiente forma

```
<embed id="doc" class="doc w-100 h-100" src="../prueba.php#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0">
```

Me gustaría ocultar el solo el menú lateral que se ve en el PDF, ya que si pongo toolbar = 0, desaparecen todas las herramientas como se ve en ambas imágenes

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]